# Can you help identify my roller door side track tape?

Tags: garage-door

The "tape" on my roller door is getting old and needs replacing because it's causing a lot of friction against the guides so the door does not move smoothly. I need help identifying the name of this part. I can post more photos if necessary. The "tape" appears to be rubber with a woven fibre type coating.

[image: roller door full view]

[image: tape detail view]

Comment: I'm not a garage door expert by any means, but some internet searching has failed to turn up any parts for the door itself. I'm not sure you'll be able to find a replacement for just the "tape" along the edges. I'd suggest contacting a couple of local garage door companies, though they may only do standard residential sectional doors. Maybe get hold of the owner/manager of a self-storage place that has roll up doors to find out who they have do maintenance on their roll-up doors. Based on the condition of the door itself in that close up, it might not be bad to replace the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Its called Nylofelt.

B&D claim it as their invention. Good luck finding it for sale.

Comment: Who is "B&D"? Is that "Black & Decker"? If not, a link to a web site for reference might be helpful.

Comment: https://www.bnd.com.au/explore/resource-hub/our-blog/a-guide-to-roller-garage-doors/ simply identifies it as "B&D".  This old ad simply also simply refers to "B&D" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAEgIet0gAI